# syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '['

Tags: php, laravel

Выбивает ошибку: "  syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '['  "

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $path =&gt; public_path().'\upload\\';
        $file = $request->file('file');

        foreach ($file as $f) {
            $filename = str_random(20) .'.' . $f->getClientOriginalExtension() ?: 'png';
            $img = ImageInt::make($f);
            $img->resize(200,200)->save($path . $filename);
            Image::create(['title' => $request->title, 'img' => $filename]);
        }

        return redirect()->route('images.index');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не обернули `&gt;` в строку

```
$path ='&gt;'.public_path().'\upload\\';
```